# Word for a person who represents everyone

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to fill in the following phrase on my school elections. "Foreign by birth. __________ for all." In the blank I was thinking "people's person", "representation for all".

I want a word that means a person who represents everyone and everyone's wishes.

Not anything like politician.

Comment: Advocate for all?

Comment: @WS2 It's a one word.

Comment: Ok. *Advocate*, then.

Comment: Let it be your username :)

Answer (score 1):

> Foreign by birth, *Representative* for all.

Seems least contentious; it implies a person's loyalty to the general civic interest.  "Representative" here can be either a noun (one who represents on behalf of others) or an adjective (as in 'a representative sample'), or can be understood both ways.

Whereas "*represent**ation*** for all" suggests correcting for some perceived under-representation of minority interests.

Answer (score 0):

In literature and drama, the term "**[Everyman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everyman)**" has come to mean an ordinary individual, with whom the audience or reader is supposed to be able to identify easily.

I think this most closely represents what you are looking for.